# Add a JavaScript Event to an Image With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, image

Ok so I'm going to try and make this as clear as possible. I want to write a function that when called will add an `onmouseout` attribute to an image.

Before the image is moused over.

```
<img src="myfile.jpg" onmouseover="function()" />
```

After

```
<img src="myfile.jpg" onmouseover="function()" onmouseout="anotherFunction()" />
```

I would also like to change the picture with `function()` and then onmouseout set the picture back to the original. I know how to change the pictures with onmouseover and onmouseout right in the image code but I'm trying to simplify this as I have to do the image changy thing about 100 times and I dont want to write out the code that many times. Gah I hope that was clear.

Comment: Any objections to using JQuery?

Comment: Do you have the same functions to be applied on every image?

Comment: @webnoob, give me a break. jQuery is not tagged. jQuery and JS are not synonymous.

Comment: jquery is a javascript library. Probably you are still not aware of it, but it's worth the look if you are into javascript. http://jquery.com

Comment: @JamesHill - Had JQuery been tagged I wouldn't of asked the question in a comment. If JQuery is being used anywhere else on the site then it would avoid inline JS / messing about with attaching events.

Comment: @webnoob I cannot use jquery. It is not supported with what I am doing

Comment: @ChapmIndustries heard of addEventListner() ??

Comment: well using `addEventlistener` you can attach and bind event like mouseover, mouseenter... to every element. like on every image on the page. would you like me to provide you with a sample code?

Comment: @Saurabh Ok see now that's what Im lookin for. James Hill seems to have added this to his but if you whip together a sample code Ill check you as the answer.

Comment: hold on for a couple of minutes, i'll give a sample code with jsfiddle

Comment: @ChapmIndustries, by all means, ask someone else to duplicate my answer so you can mark it as correct...

Comment: @JamesHill he came up with it and then it appeared on yours...I want to give credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go http://jsfiddle.net/5U9w9/2/

I'm going to update the jsFidle with more comments and will update the link here too.

**javascript**

```
// grab all the required element on the page
var img_all = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

// for every element do this
for (i=0; i< img_all.length; i++){
    var img = img_all[i];
    // set the required event on the element
    // when the event of the element occurs, the associated function will be called with event object as it's argument.
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference
    //img.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseover_handler, false);
    AddEvent(img, 'mouseover', mouseover_handler) 

    //mouseout_handler will be called, on mouseout event
    // img.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseout_handler, false);
    AddEvent(img, 'mouseout', mouseout_handler)
}


function mouseover_handler(e){
    // el is and event object and has various properties like clientX, clientY, srcElement, etc. you can check them by console.log(el)
    console.log(e)

    // to get the element i'm hovering, use
    var element = e.srcElement;

    //element is DOM element and can be manupulated
    element.style.width="100px";
}

// similarly handler for an another event.
function mouseout_handler(e){
    e.srcElement.style.width="50px";
}

​// cross-browser addEventListner
function AddEvent(html_element, event_name, event_function) 
{       
   if(html_element.attachEvent) //Internet Explorer
      html_element.attachEvent("on" + event_name, function() {event_function.call(html_element);}); 
   else if(html_element.addEventListener) // Everything else
      html_element.addEventListener(event_name, event_function, false);
}
```

**Update**

- Use `AddEvent` in the place of `addEventListner()` for IE support.​ (CREDIT: @James Hill's answer)

Comment: well, you can use AddEvent() from @James answer. It basically checks if addEventListener function is available or not and uses the appropriate alternative. :)

Comment: i'm going to update the code that so that it remain helpful for others too.

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler than you may think:

```
function SetImageSource(ele, url) {
    ele.src = url;
}

<img src="myfile.jpg" 
     onmouseover="SetImageSource(this, 'someURL')"
     onmouseout="SetImageSource(this, 'someOtherURL')" />
```

**Note:** Inline JavaScript is not ideal. I suggest reading up on event handling in JS. More specifically, read about attaching to an event.

**Edit per clarification**

```
<img id="imgMyImage" src="myfile.jpg" 
     onmouseover="SetImageSource(this, 'someURL')"
     onmouseout="SetImageSource(this, 'someOtherURL')" />


function AddEvent(html_element, event_name, event_function) 
{       
   if(html_element.attachEvent) //Internet Explorer
      html_element.attachEvent("on" + event_name, function() {event_function.call(html_element);}); 
   else if(html_element.addEventListener) // Everything else
      html_element.addEventListener(event_name, event_function, false);
}

AddEvent(document.getElementById('imgMyImage'),
                                 'onmouseover',
                                 // do something
                                 );
```

**Additional Information**

See [`.addEventListener()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)

See [`.attachEvent()` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah but I dont want to have to type onmouseout at all. Otherwise I would just type onmouseout="this.src="blah"

Comment: Why not type it? Bit of an odd requirement.

Comment: @webnoob Because typing it is a monstrous pain in the ass when you are going to do it 1230981234981234 times

Comment: Are you using any server side code? Could it be done dynamically?